# Не вставляет картинку в RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, изображения, richtextbox

Пытаюсь вставить картинку в RichTextBox разными способами, но она не отображается.

```
Image img = Image.FromFile("is_smile.png");
Clipboard.Clear();
Clipboard.SetImage(img);
richTextBox1.Paste();
Clipboard.Clear();
```

или так

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(@"is_smile.png");
Clipboard.SetDataObject(img);
DataFormats.Format dataFormat = 
DataFormats.GetFormat(DataFormats.Bitmap);
if (richTextBox1.CanPaste(dataFormat))
{
    richTextBox1.Paste(dataFormat);
}
```

или так

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.is_smile); 
Clipboard.SetDataObject(myBitmap);
DataFormats.Format myFormat = DataFormats.GetFormat(DataFormats.Bitmap);
richTextBox1.Paste(myFormat);
```

Результат вечно один, картинка не вставляется. Ну или она так вставляется, что ее не видно.

Воспользовался этой статьей, но при попытке заменить символ на картинку, у меня вообще просто зависает приложение csharpdemos.blogspot.com/2012/10/… . А все потому что я сначала пишу в TextBox и отправлю символы в RichTextBox, а после уже проверяю символы в RichTextBox для замены на картинку.

---

Использую замену символов в тексте на картинку, но при добавлении нового текста в новой строке картинка, которая была раньше, исчезнет.

```
Hashtable emotions;

void CreateEmotions()
{
    emotions = new Hashtable(2);
    emotions.Add(":-)", Properties.Resources.is_smile);
    emotions.Add(":)", Properties.Resources.is_smile);
}

void AddEmotions()
{
    foreach (string emote in emotions.Keys)
    {
        while (richTextBox1.Text.Contains(emote))
        {
            int ind = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(emote);
            richTextBox1.Select(ind, emote.Length);
            Clipboard.SetImage((Image)emotions[emote]);
            richTextBox1.Paste();
        }
    }
}

private void richTextBox1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddEmotions();
}
```

Comment: У меня первый способ работает, вставляет картинку. Файл `is_smile.png` точно не битый и лежит где надо? На разных файлах пробовали? Покажите, что у вас в RTB на момент вставки (желательно, сырой RTF).

Comment: файл точно нормальный и лежит где надо, так как picturebox выводит нормально. показывать rtb не смысла, так как он пустой остается на момент вставки. Пробивал пошагово - переменная с картинкой, не пустая.

Comment: Вполне рабочий код. Учитывая слова _зависает приложение_ могу предположить, что у вас некоторые действия выполняются в (бесконечном?) цикле в gui-потоке.

Comment: боже вся причина была в readOnly что там стояло True. А как же мне запретить писать в rtb, а только отображаться в нем изменения?

Comment: И как же вставлять картинку с новой строки и чтоб она не исчезала когда добавиться новый текст.

Comment: Вы можете снять флаг readOnly перед вставкой, потом установить его назад. *"И как же вставлять картинку с новой строки"* - просто добавить `\n` перед ней?

Comment: это да, но картинка всеравно исчезает, когда добавляется новая строка

Comment: `Enabled = false;` - это даст возможность программно менять текст в rtb, но пользователь не сможет этого делать. Правда, при этом фон изменится.

Comment: та это я как бы смог догадаться, с риадонли лучше. Это все хорошо, но все избегают ответа или просто не знают как сделать чтобы картинки не пропадали с ртб.

Comment: Ничего не отвечают очевидно потому, что ни у кого ничего не пропадает. Приведите больше кода, приводящего к проблеме.

Comment: Попробовал я ваш код. Работает. Картинка вставляется, ничего не исчезает. | Я бы заменил устаревший `Hashtable` на `Dictionary<string, Image>`. И после вставки изображения желательно курсор передвинуть за неё.

Comment: воспользовался Dictionaty и в AddEmotions() отредактировал код вставки изображения и переноса строки int posTemp = chatTextBox.SelectionStart;
                    chatTextBox.Paste();
                    chatTextBox.SelectionStart = posTemp;
                    chatTextBox.SelectionLength = 0; Но всеравно пропадает картинка

Comment: в доказательство две фото с процесса https://ibb.co/nBrn2bw
https://ibb.co/7gfsVn7